# Выделяется ли запятыми слово "дурак"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп, приложение

> *Да я же тебе говорил, а ты, дурак, не понял ничего!*

Слово *дурак* здесь выделяется запятыми на базовых основаниях (как приложение после личного местоимения)? Нет ли в данном случае какого-то нюанса из базового правила?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думается, что "дурак" в этом предложении вполне может быть обычным обращением — словечко можно без потери смысла переставить в любую другую часть предложения.
Сравните:
*Дурак, да я же тебе говорил, а ты не понял ничего!*
*Понял? Ничего ты не понял и не поймешь никогда, дурак!* (Н. Коляда. Вор)

Мне кажется, что однозначно понять — приложение это или обращение — можно только тогда, когда местоимение стоит в падеже.
*У **тебя, дурака**, нет проблем* — приложение (склоняется).
*У **тебя, дурак**, нет проблем* — обращение (не склоняется).

Для сведения и просто для того, чтобы всем поднять настроение:
**[Дядя Петя, ты дурак?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pj-XvFoWI7g)** (здесь "дурак" является сказуемым)

Answer (score 1):

Вместо запятой при обособлении приложений может использоваться тире... Если приложение стоит в середине предложения и имеет пояснительный характер (тире ставится с двух сторон).

> Какая-то ненатуральная зелень – творение скучных беспрерывных дождей –
>   покрывала жидкою сетью поля и нивы (*Н. Гоголь*).

https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/718-242_obosoblenie_prilozhenii.html

Comment: Извините, а зачем две совершенно одинаковых ссылки?